# problem installing tensorflow

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I tried installing tensorflow using pip by:

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
.........
Installing collected packages: enum34, grpcio, pbr, funcsigs, mock, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: enum34 1.1.2
Cannot uninstall 'enum34'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I tried removing enum34 using:

```
sudo apt remove enum34
```

But it does not seem to be working.

```
E: Unable to locate package enum34
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post seemed to help me uninstalling enum34:
http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/main/p/python-enum34/uninstall/index.html